# how to impliment background process in iphone phone gap sdk

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am new in iphone phone gap developement. and i have a task to work with back ground process.

I have to impliment the background task to run the background and at the spacific time i have to send the latitude and longitude to the server. but the main problem is that i have a task to develop whole application in phone gap,so do not have idea about how to impliment background process in iphone phone gap sdk.

Please help me and provide me any code or example if it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks i have solved their is method to solve this problem and with the help of javascript we can also create background process.

Comment: How to create the background process using java script. because as per my knowledge java script can not run in the background

Comment: please provide some links or at least some conceptual examples